communicate between devices over local network with socket in python
I wrote a simple programe to make a communicate between my PC and my Android mobile over local network but my code produce an error and I can't figure out what problem is .
Client script works properly on pc but it doesn't work on mobile
Server
import socket 


PORT = 1700
IP = '0.0.0.0'

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)

server.bind((IP , PORT))

server.listen(5)

while True :
    client , addr = server.accept()
    print(client)
    print(addr)
    exit()


Client
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.1.7' , 1700))

Error
OSError : [Errno 113] No route to host

I tried unblocking port 1700 on my computer but the result did not change.

Why does your server code have: IP = '0.0.0.0'?

Because that's the address that means "bind to all interfaces" (aka INADDR_ANY). See e.g. wikipedia.

This line: "s.connect(('192.168.1.7' , 1700))" tells me that you're connecting though a home router.  Like, your android is the 7th device to connect to your router, and that means that you'll also need to open op the port 1700 for that device on your router.  Also, your router could re-assign this IP address, so you'll need to be careful there.

@VoNWooDSoN: 192.168.1.7 is an address on the local network. There is no need to open the port for this on the router since it is not coming from the internet (local IP are not routable on the internet). Of course, this means that the device need to be in the same LAN; but that's what the OP claims.

Are you sure that the mobile device is connected to the same (W)LAN as your target system? Have you checked that the mobile device has an IP address on the LAN, i.e. something like 192.168.1.x (check settings  | About phone | IP address)?
